# Highcharts cut my series - transform bad position

Tags: highcharts

I got some problem with highcharts.

Try to transform the highcharts series or series group on correct.

[ch1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBtaO.png)

Bottom "grid" cut my spline and I dont know why. Try to formate like this: 
[ch2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54uh7.png)

Comment: You are going to need to post code on how you are achieving your chart so we can replicate the issue. I think what you are asking is how to not get the series line clipped when it goes to 0 on the yAxis.

Comment: Example on jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/offset/
the 0 yAxis is half on width, overflow ? How to show full line on 0 position

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the plot area which is limited by the axes. You should set yAxis min to be a little lower than the cut point and set [yAxis.startOnTick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.startOnTick) to false.

```
yAxis: {
        lineWidth: 2,
        startOnTick: false,
        min: -2,
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/jecp8jac/